# How to display maxlength of input as user starts typing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maxlength

The input field of my website looks like this:[(click here to view image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ma7b.png)

It's code in jsx file looks like this:

```
render: function () {
    return (
        <form id="addcourse" role="form" className="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" ref="courseForm">
            <fieldset>
                <CategoryLoader callback={this.handleCategoryChange}/>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">Title</label>
                    <div className="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
                        <input name="title" type="text"  maxLength="6" id="abcd" className="form-control" ref="title" placeholder="Title (Maximum 100 characters)"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">Course Image</label>
                    <div className="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
                        <input name="image" type="file" className="form-control" ref="image"/>
                        <p className="help-block">Upload image for the course </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">Enrollment Type</label>
                    <div className="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
                        <select ref="enrollment_type" name="enrollment_type" className="form-control">
                            <option value="O">Open</option>
                            <option value="M">Moderated</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2  addcoursebutton">
                        <button ref="submit" className="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick={this.add_course}>Add
                            Course
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-1">
                        <button type="button" onClick={this.props.closeCallBack} className="btn btn-danger">
                            Close
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    );
```

I've tried maxLength="6".

It won't take more than 6 characters in input but it doesn't give any error like "Maximum length is 6 characters."

So, when the user starts typing in that field, I want it to display a message under input field,"Maximum of 6 characters are allowed".

How can I do that?

Comment: Your 'question' kinda just states your requirement rather than any specific issues. Do you only want to display the message when they try to type more than that? If so you can add an `onKeyPress` handler to the `<input/>` that checks the length whenever they try to type something and add logic to display an error if the input value is already 6 characters. Could just be a simple bool in state then conditionally render an element with the desired 'max chars=6' error message. That's just one example.

Comment: do you use jQuery in your project ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(elementId).onchange(function(){
var len = this.val.length;
if (len > 5)
alert("You cannot exceed max of 6 characters").
});
```

you can also use 'onkeypress' event as well and any other type of result than alert, whatever suits

Comment: I have that above code in jsx file in a function. Can I put the code you've given in jsx file? Will it work?

Comment: yes it should.. try it . .but you have to put correct 'elementid' (your input element id) I have just use variable name..

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple and react way of doing this is using state.
if you need more explanation let me know. hope this will help.

```
checkMaxLen = e => {
    if (e.target.value.length > 6) {
      this.setState({ errorText: "Length cant exceed more then 6" });
    } else {
      if (this.errorText) {
        this.setState({ errorText: "" });
      }
    }
  };


<input type="text"
  onChange={this.checkMaxLen}
/>
{this.state.errorText && <span>{this.state.errorText}</span>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even achieve it with CSS only. Here is [the explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text)